# Should one say "for forever" or "forever"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I've always wondered about this.

When describing an exaggerated amount of time should one say "for forever" or "forever"?

As in:

> I have been waiting for forever.

or

> I have been waiting forever.

The argument being that the word "forever" is in itself a period of time, or it isn't.

Comment: Doesn't your first sentence sound a bit, weird?

Comment: Actually, I prefer *I have been waiting for ever*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Forever" in this context is an adverb. You could also say that it's basically "for ever" without the space. As such, if you're saying that you have been waiting for a very long time, then the latter usage is right.

In the former usage, "forever" is used as a noun. It does not describe *how long* you have been waiting; instead, as a noun, it represents *what* you're waiting for. In other words, it means you're waiting for *forever*, as in the period of time itself, which may itself either refer to an indeterminate point in time in the future or an indefinitely long duration of time.

Comment: To wrap up BoltClock's answer, the correct use for your intended meaning is in sentence two.